# What is this green component from a camera flash unit?

Tags: identification, components

I recently opened up an old camera. I tore it down to its flash unit.

[image: camera flash components and PCB]

I saw this green  component and I'm not sure what exactly it is.

[image: unknown component]

It also has a small rod which fits inside the hole. When I opened up the camera in the first place, the rod was already inserted completely inside the hole. (Sorry no image of the rod because I lost it.) My guess is that it is some kind of inductor. However I'm not sure, because of the rod inclusion in it and also the entire component is dangling onto the copper wires, as shown in the image. I tried to Google some answers, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Did the camera have a spring loaded pop-up flash bulb? If so it's likely the release solenoid for that.

Comment: No it did have a spring loaded pop up flash bulb..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a solenoid, probably to release the shutter mechanism. The rod is pulled into the coil when power is applied to the solenoid coil.

Comment: Would you mean to say that the rod is actually being inserted and removed physically when the camera is working?? Or it is just there for proper powering ??

Comment: I would expect the rod to push against something when it is pulled into the solenoid and release a latch or something of that ilk. The available force of such a solenoid is fairly light and it can only be powered intermittently (short and occasional pulses) or it would drain the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Magnet wire and cylindrical shape define a solenoid for latching and unlatching moving parts.